# Iterate through API using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I am using the following API and need to select a few items from the list (OrgName, MaxSeats and userCount) from the data for each Org. Previous attempts got close, but I could never even as a single object pull userCount.

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $api_user 'https://console.us.code42.com/api/org?active=true&inccount=True&incsettings=True' -Method Get -UseBasicParsing |
    Select-Object Content |
    ConvertTo-Json).PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$($_.name): $($_.value)"
    }
```

API I am calling is the same URL above; full description can be found here: https://console.us.code42.com/apidocviewer

Adding output from `Invoke-RestMethod`.

I did start with `Invoke-RestMethod` and got the closest there; but read elsewhere that `Invoke-WebRequest` was preferred. The output from just the standard call is here, the OrgName and MaxSeats are there - but I know that `userCount` is also something available via the API if I iterate for each ORG.

```
orgId                   : 2633
orgUid                  : xxxxxx
orgName                 : B Team
orgExtRef               : 
notes                   : 
status                  : Active
active                  : True
blocked                 : False
parentOrgId             : 1167
parentOrgUid            : xxxxxx
type                    : ENTERPRISE
classification          : BASIC
externalId              : xxxxxx
hierarchyCounts         : 
configInheritanceCounts : 
creationDate            : 2/10/19 11:45:48 PM
modificationDate        : 2/10/19 11:45:48 PM
deactivationDate        : 
registrationKey         : xxxxxxxx
reporting               : @{orgManagers=System.Object[]}
customConfig            : False
settings                : @{maxSeats=; maxBytes=}
settingsInherited       : @{maxSeats=; maxBytes=}
settingsSummary         : @{maxSeats=; maxBytes=}
```

If you look at the actual API, it lists a lot of other items which are not seen here. I guess that's the big question.

Raw JSON output from my API call - which shows differently from documentation page.

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp": "2019-03-01T12:50:36.296Z",
    "params": {
      "incsettings": "True",
      "active": "true",
      "inccount": "True"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "totalCount": 4,
    "orgs": [
      "@{orgId=1172; orgUid=xxxx; orgName=A Team; orgExtRef=; notes=; status=Active; active=True; blocked=False; parentOrgId=1167; parentOrgUid=xxxx; type=ENTERPRISE; classification=BASIC; externalId=xxxx; hierarchyCounts=; configInheritanceCounts=; creationDate=04/22/2018 17:49:30; modificationDate=02/10/2019 23:44:27; deactivationDate=; registrationKey=xxxx; reporting=; customConfig=False; settings=; settingsInherited=; settingsSummary=}",
      "@{orgId=1173; orgUid=xxxx; orgName=Jurassic Park; orgExtRef=; notes=; status=Active; active=True; blocked=False; parentOrgId=1167; parentOrgUid=xxxx; type=ENTERPRISE; classification=BASIC; externalId=xxxx; hierarchyCounts=; configInheritanceCounts=; creationDate=04/22/2018 17:51:41; modificationDate=02/10/2019 23:26:07; deactivationDate=; registrationKey=xxxx; reporting=; customConfig=False; settings=; settingsInherited=; settingsSummary=}",
      "@{orgId=2633; orgUid=xxxx; orgName=B Team; orgExtRef=; notes=; status=Active; active=True; blocked=False; parentOrgId=1167; parentOrgUid=xxxx; type=ENTERPRISE; classification=BASIC; externalId=xxxx; hierarchyCounts=; configInheritanceCounts=; creationDate=02/10/2019 23:45:48; modificationDate=02/10/2019 23:45:48; deactivationDate=; registrationKey=xxxx; reporting=; customConfig=False; settings=; settingsInherited=; settingsSummary=}",
      "@{orgId=1167; orgUid=xxxx; orgName=Eric Hall SAAS SE Test - Backup; orgExtRef=; notes=; status=Active; active=True; blocked=False; parentOrgId=1121; parentOrgUid=xxxx; type=ENTERPRISE; classification=BASIC; externalId=xxxx; hierarchyCounts=; configInheritanceCounts=; creationDate=04/20/2018 21:10:03; modificationDate=02/10/2019 23:36:20; deactivationDate=; registrationKey=xxxx; reporting=; customConfig=False; settings=; settingsInherited=; settingsSummary=}"
    ]
  }
}
```

The MAXSEATS Field appears in the settings blocks (though not seen here)

Comment: The response I am getting from this is:
Length:18
I'm not sure where I am getting this wrong.

Comment: I suggest you make your web call and load the web result into a variable and experiment with that result. If you post the result from this web call as JSON we may be able to help but as is we have no idea of the structure.

Comment: Also try `Invoke-RESTmethod` instead of `Invoke-Webrequest`.

Comment: I do feel your pain - I know that Powershell can do this but it seems like mostly black  magic to me. The first step is to capture the result in a variable then you can interact with that adhoc in the Powershell console. I checked your link and the sample JSON doesn't have any of the attributes mentioned in your question,

Comment: Oh apologies, those attributes are there but which JSON response are you after exactly?

Comment: Updated the post - looking for orgname, maxseats (under settings) and userCount which is not seen in the output above.

Comment: According to the API documentation the value you're looking for should be available on the same level of hierarchy as `orgId`. Please update your question with the raw JSON response from the server. You may obfuscate sensitive information, but keep the structure intact.

Comment: Added additional info requested.

Comment: Can you do that again, but this time using `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100` please?